# All files unattached in Media Library, need a way to re-attach them

Tags: php, wordpress

For a few months I used a plugin that automatically downloads remote images and save them. However, I found there's about 15 000 unattached images, that are actually in posts. The plugin never attached the images to the post itself.

I have no idea what to do or how to solve this. I can't do it manually it will take ages.
Is there a way to scan the images and re-attach them to the respective post?

Update: After I run the below plugin that Sergiu mentioned. The report shows:

[image]

So it does seem to pick up the images in the post. I just wish it can attach it somehow to that post ID. Is there a way to modify the code?

In the plugin below. In line 525 i removed the code:

```
if (  stripos( $img, $path ) !== false ) {
                    $response .= 'Img already in media library<br>';
                    continue;
                }
```

Now it attaches the images!
Only one last issue is that it makes new copies. I can't find a way for it to not re-download them. I prefer it to just attach them.

Here is, what i think the full piece of code responsible. Please suggest modifications:

http://pastebin.com/ePERuGjt#

```
/**
 * Extracts all images in content adds to media library if external and updates content with new url
 * @param object $post The post object
 * @return array|bool Post id and images converted on success false if no images found in source
 */
function extract_multi( $post ) {
        $html = $post->post_content;
        $path = wp_upload_dir();
        $path = $path['baseurl'];
        $error = 0;
        $response = '';
        if ( stripos( $html, '<img' ) !== false ) {

                $regex = '#<\s*img [^\>]*src\s*=\s*(["\'])(.*?)\1#im';
                preg_match_all( $regex, $html, $matches );

                if ( is_array( $matches ) && ! empty( $matches ) ) {
                        $new = array();
                        $old = array();
                        foreach( $matches[2] as $img ) {
                                /** Compare image source against upload directory to prevent adding same attachment multiple times  */



                                $tmp = download_url( $img );

                                preg_match('/[^\?]+\.(jpg|JPG|jpe|JPE|jpeg|JPEG|gif|GIF|png|PNG)/', $img, $matches);
                                $file_array['name'] = basename($matches[0]);
                                $file_array['tmp_name'] = $tmp;
                                // If error storing temporarily, unlink
                if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
                    @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
                    $file_array['tmp_name'] = '';
                        continue;
                }

                                $id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post->ID );

                                if ( ! is_wp_error( $id ) ) {
                                        $url  = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
                                        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $id );
                                        array_push( $new, $url );
                                        array_push( $old, $img );

                                        $response .= '<p><a href="'. wp_nonce_url( get_edit_post_link( $id, true ) ).'" title="edit-image"><img src="'.esc_url( $thumb ).'" style="max-width:100px;" /></a><br>';
                                        $response .= '<a href="'. wp_nonce_url( get_edit_post_link( $id, true ) ).'" >'.get_the_title( $id ). '</a>  Imported and attached</p>';
                                } else {
                                        $response .= '<span style="color:red">Upload Error: Could not upload image. Check for malformed img src url</span><br>';
                                        $error ++;
                                }
                        }
                        if( !empty( $new ) ) {
                                $content = str_ireplace( $old, $new, $html );
                                $post_args = array( 'ID' => $post->ID, 'post_content' => $content, );
                                if ( !empty( $content ) )
                                        $post_id = wp_update_post( $post_args );
                                        if ( isset( $post_id ) )
                                                $response .= 'Post Content updated for Post: '.esc_html( $post->post_title).'<br>';
                                        return array( 'error' => $error, 'response' => $response );
                        } else
                                 $response .= 'No external images found for ' . esc_html( $post->post_title ) . '<br>';
                                return array ( 'error' => $error, 'response' => $response );

                } else {
                         $response .= 'Error processing images for '. esc_html( $post->post_title ) .'<br>';
                        return array ( 'error' => $error, 'response' => $response );
                  }
        } else {
                 $response .= 'No images found for ' . esc_html( $post->post_title) . '<br>';
                return array ( 'error' => $error, 'response' => $response );
          }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This plugin](https://github.com/c3mdigital/media-tools-for-WordPress) seems to implement a feature dealing with exactly your problem.

Comment: Thanks Sergiu, that plugin seems really useful in a lot of situations. However my images are already downloaded and local. It does not seem to reattach them to the post. I updated my question to show the report.

Comment: @user1083148 , what about making and saving a backup copy of your media library, then deleting all the images and trying this suggestion again? You may have to manually replace some images that were always local, but if it can fix the 15,000 odd external images you are doing OK ;)

Comment: Yup...you are right. Seems your only hope would be to write your own. You could try talking to the guy who implemented that one, should be a pretty simple change.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know programming. If you want to have a quick scan through the plugin and make the modification so that it attach all images and not just remote images, I can donate $20 $30. But if it is complicated and does not work the first run, we can leave it.

Comment: No donation needed, if you can't find another solution till Monday I'll come with something up.

Comment: Progress! In line 525 i removed some code. I will paste it on top. Now it attaches the images!  However, it makes new copies and attach them. I cannot find a way so it just attaches it and not need to download it again.  But at least some progress.

Comment: I finally solved it by modifying the above plugin. Thanks again Sergiu.

Answer (score 2):

I am the original poster for this problem. After a few years, I came across this old post. I dug up the solution, in the hopes that it might help anyone in the future.

This is the modified media-tools.php file:

https://pastebin.com/8iUT78aP

Just install Media Tools plugin: https://github.com/c3mdigital/media-tools-for-WordPress

and overwrite the pastebin with the media-tools.php

Then, the plugin will actually re-attached all unattached media to the proper posts, also without re-downloading the images.

I hope this helps someone, as this problem is pure hell to solve.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest doing this way:

1. wget your site
   wget -m http://yoursite.com
   this should mirror all your site.
   wget WILL NOT download unatached images.
2. check if everything was downloaded
3. delete wp-content directory (i mean dir where your images are stored)
4. upload files downloaded by wget.

next time use: DX Delete Attached Media Plugin.
it deletes all images attached to posts, when post is deleted.